# iphone bluetooth connection

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

is there an iOS api to communicate to a paired bluetooth device?   Looking for a starting point.

Thanks in advance!

Rob

Answer (score 4):

Like ing0 said you can use GameKit. But it depends what you want to do with bluetooth. You can't access the bluetooth PAN by default, and the lower level bluetooth API requires that you sign an agreement with Apple and join the MFi (made for iPod) program to make a hardware divice that works with Bluetooth.

http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

Answer (score 1):

Read up on the *GameKit framework*. There are some good examples on Apple's Resources sending and receiving byte arrays. This definitely works with other iDevices but not sure about any old device...